# How do I draw a line in Titanium?

Tags: iphone, android, titanium

How Do I draw a line in Titanium that works in both Android and iPhone?

Comment: It's a very interesting question. I see we can easily draw a vertical or horizontal line in Titanium by emulate it by a fake label. But how about the cross line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create  webview and use the `<canvas>` tag to draw in the web view

Answer (score 5):

To create a line, I use;

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    height:180,
    width:300
});

var line = Ti.UI.createView({
    height:2,
    bottom:0,
    left:0,
    right:0,
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'#aaa'
 });

view.add(line);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your view.xml

```
<View class="line"></View>
```

Add this to your style.tss

```
".line": {
    height: '2dp',
    bottom: '2dp',
    left: '0dp',
    right: '0dp',
    borderWidth: '1',
    borderColor:'#aaa',
}
```