# How to draw line between two coordinates in iphone application using titanium?

Tags: iphone, titanium

I am implementing one stock display ipad application in which i want to display graph.
But I dont know how to draw graph.I want to draw graph in view not in webview.
I have tried to find  out on google.But not got success.
Can you please give us advice about this query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you ever consider to use a webview, there is a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981206/how-do-i-draw-a-line-in-titanium

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following tutorial to teach you how to draw lines on a view. Found with a simple [Google](http://www.google.co.za/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=iphone+drawing+a+line+tutorial) search ;-) http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024

Comment: Yes  you are right but it is for core iphone application.But I want using Titanium..

Comment: Please advice me how it possible using titanium.

Comment: Let me get one thing straight first, Titanium allows you to use JavaScript and all those web technologies to create native apps right?

Comment: Yes you are right.But not excatly webtechnology....In background it use iphone sdk

Comment: Can't you then use jQuery libraries to draw graphs? Sorry I have no experience with Titanium and any other cross platforms stuff like it, I do native development in the native languages. But certainly using the jQuery Graphs will allow you to draw your graphs, as jQuery is still JavaScript? Missed the Titanium part in your question sorry.

Comment: Yes somthing like that...Thanks buddy.But if you get anything regarding titanium for graph then please let me know..My email id is dalalmanthan@gmail.com

Comment: @Armand, not exactly. While Titanium is JavaScript it isn't using web technologies.